# Как задать такое форматирование кода

Tags: php

У меня вопрос возможно ли настроить вот такое форматирование кода в любой ide(желательно в моей родной ide phpdisigner 8) фишка в том что бы все методы были вот так в колонку.
[image]

Comment: Таб не работает?

Comment: скажи почему на строчках 17-18 они не переносятся? Почему с 22-ой строки они тоже как-то в строчку записаны?

Comment: Я про автоформатирование спрашивал.

Comment: Вопрос непонятный! Хотите, чтобы IDE выравнивала методы с новой строки? Или хотите чтобы методы шли последовательно друг из друга?

Comment: и так и так, гляньте на картинке.

Comment: @ukroficer, для второго пункта надо сделать так, чтобы каждый метод возвращал this, то есть экземпляр объекта. Для первого, увы, автоформат можно настроить только вручную (если мне не изменяет память). Но про phpdesigner не могу сказать.

Comment: Нет на счет this я понимаю)))Это ведь мой код... И я делаю его руками, но это мне не нравиться совсем. Кто то еще так форматирует?

Comment: @ukroficer ты выбрал самую ужасную IDE для программирования на `php`. Видимо, ты пока не знаешь кто такие `JetBrains`. В добавок, стили в твоем редакторе, ужасны, и от этой цветовой раскраски, при длительной работе, глаза будут тебя тихо ненавидеть

Answer (score 1):

Используйте PHP-Storm там такое форматирование "Из коробки" - так же вы сможете выбрать шаблоны и настроить - скажем что бы на C++ подобном синтаксисе было скажем Python-подобное форматирование.